# Can we implement Angular microfrontend using angular-devkit?

Tags: angular, webpack-4, angular-devkit, ngx-build-plus

I have recently gained an interest in developing microfrontends using module-federation, and I have started converting an existing Angular 13 app to microfrontend. The issue that I'm facing is that when I install module-federation, the default builder for the microfrontend is ngx-build-plus. However, my existing app is built using angular-devkit. I also read that webpack supports only ngx-build. Is there a way for me to find a workaround for this?
I need to use angular-devkit since the project I'm working on is pretty big and can't be converted to ngx-build.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with “when I install module-federation, the default builder for the microfrontend is ngx-build-plus”? What is that install exactly?

Comment: The webpack.config,js files get generated when I do "npm install @angular-architects/module-federation". By default, ngx-build-plus is used as builder for the webpack components. I need to use Angular-devkit.

Comment: Ah right. I'm using that same package - however, I'm also using Nx so it's using a custom builder there (@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser). I'm not sure if it is possible to use custom webpack configs with just the angular devkit. I think the recommended way is to use the angular-builders package (https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/13.x.x/packages/custom-webpack) - which under the hood simply extends angular devkit.

Comment: Thanks!
I'll definitely look into this.